# Data source initialization error in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have the data source initialization error in Excel 2016, but I am only using tables from the same file. I have already installed all the updates but the error continues, any idea how to solve it?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uohHT.png)